# strtolower() for unicode/multibyte strings

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, lowercase, multibyte

I have some text in a non-English/foreign language in my page,
but when I try to make it lowercase, it characters are converted into black diamonds containing question marks.

```
$a = "Երկիր Ավելացնել";
echo $b = strtolower($a);
//returns  ����� ���������
```

I've set my charset in a metatag, but this didn't fix it.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What can I do to convert my string to lowercase without corrupting it?

Comment: The Unicode monster strikes again! Here, have a link: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Is there even such a thing as lower case arabic or whatever that is? :P

Comment: Make sure to send Content-Type header as well, in some browsers it takes priority over the meta tag.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Have you tried using [`mb_strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)?

Comment: var_dump(mb_strtolower('ԱԱԱ', mb_detect_encoding('ԱԱԱ'))); // string(6) "աաա" 100% Working!!!!

Answer (score 22):

PHP5 is not UTF-8 compatible, so you still need to resort to the mb extension. I suggest you set the internal encoding of mb to utf-8 and then you can freely use its functions without specifying the charset all the time:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

...

$b = mb_strtolower($a);
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 10):

i have found this solution from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/342307/utf-8-encoding-issues-with-strtolower)

```
$string = 'Թ';
echo 'Uppercase: '.mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8").'';
echo 'Lowercase: '.mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8").'';
echo 'Original: '.$string.'';
```

works for me (lower case)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [`mb_strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) and specifying the encoding as the second parameter?

The examples on that page appear to work.

You could also try:

```
$str = mb_strtolower($str, mb_detect_encoding($str));
```

Answer (score 3):

Php by default does not know about utf-8. It assumes any string is ASCII, so it strtolower converts bytes containing codes of uppercase letters A-Z to codes of lowercase a-z. As the UTF-8 non-ascii letters are written with two or more bytes, the strtolower converts each byte separately, and if the byte happens to contain code equal to letters A-Z, it is converted. In the result the sequence is broken, and it no longer represents correct character.

To change this you need to configure the mbstring extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

to replace strtolower with mb_strtolower or use mb_strtolower direclty. I any case, you need to spend some time to configure the mbstring settings to match your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/mb_strtolower) instead, as strtolower doesn't work on multi-byte characters.

Comment: `strtolower` does actually work on multibyte characters, it just works off of the current locale, which is not usually what you want in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

strtolower() will perform the conversion in the currently selected locale only.

I would try [mb_convert_case()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php). Make sure you explicitly specify an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the locale; see the first example at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php