# How to make first letter of a word capital?

Tags: php, uppercase, ucfirst

I have a word `default` and I want a php function to make only first letter capital. Can we do that. Please help me out as I am very new to php coding.

Comment: http://php.net/results.php?q=first%2520letter%2520of%2520word%2520capital&l=en&p=wholesite

Comment: First search result on Google: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=How+to+make+first+letter+of+a+word+capital+php

Comment: Thanks I will keep the track of this site!

Comment: You should try some searching on the web, because if you would searched for it on the Google you would have been got a correct answer in first place. Just keep this in mind first search and if not get the correct answer then ask.

Comment: Thanks Jack Billy, I think from next time I will do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may want to use [ucfirst()](http://php.net/ucfirst).

For multibyte strings, please see [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518021/152422).

Comment: Thanks fabrik! This worked in first place and I think I will not be a beginner for any longer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

[ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) capitalizes the first letter in a string.

[ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) capitalizes every word in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Geeta you can simply use `ucwords()` php function to make every first letter of your word Upper Cased!

Hope this would help!

Comment: Well, actually this answer it's not so good. Why use `ucwords()` when you only need `ucfirst()`. Fabrik's answer is right on.

Comment: Ok. As you say Bogdan Constantinescu.

Answer (score 2):

I think that https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php is the best function here :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you need:

```
<?php

$string = 'stackoverflow';
$string = ucfirst($string);
echo $string;

?>
```