# strftime make first letter capital (uppercase) in PHP

Tags: php, strftime

I have code:

```
<?php echo strftime("%Y %B %e, %A")?>
```

In some languages I get:

> 2012 junio 3, domingo

I want that first letter of all words would be uppercase (capital), so it would look like:

> 2012 Junio 3, Domingo

I didn't find any answer in internet, does anybody have an idea? :)

Comment: You do realize that months and weekdays are not capitalized in Spanish, right?

Comment: It is the same problem in lot other languages, like lithuanian, greek, russian and etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `echo ucwords(strftime("%Y %B %e, %A"));`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Answer (score 5):

```
echo ucwords(strftime("%Y %B %e, %A"));
```

Comment: Given that `strftime()` provides a localised date string, and some localisations use multi-byte character sets, it would be wise to take that into account. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517947/ucfirst-function-for-multibyte-character-encodings for an example of how to write a multi-byte-characterset-safe ucfirst() function.

Answer (score 2):

ucwords is your function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Answer (score 1):

Try styling the output like this:

```
strftime('<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">%Y %B %e, %A</span>')
```

or

```
echo '<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">' . strftime('%Y %B %e, %A') . '</span>';
```

This way you can choose which words to capitalize. In your case `ucwords` works I guess, since you want all your words starting with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $x = strftime("%Y %B %e, %A");
php > $str = explode(" ", $x);
php > foreach ($str as $i) { print ucfirst($i) . " "; };
2012 June  3, Sunday 
php >
```