# Php function UTF-8 characters issue

Tags: php, utf-8

Here is my function that makes the first character of the first word of a sentence uppercase:

```
function sentenceCase($str)
{
    $cap = true;
    $ret = '';
    for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($str); $x++) {
        $letter = substr($str, $x, 1);
        if ($letter == "." || $letter == "!" || $letter == "?") {
            $cap = true;
        } elseif ($letter != " " && $cap == true) {
            $letter = strtoupper($letter);
            $cap = false;
        }
        $ret .= $letter;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

It converts "sample sentence" into "Sample sentence". The problem is, it doesn't capitalize UTF-8 characters. See [this example](http://codepad.org/08LGp1Ab).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the [`multi-byte`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) strings functions (you may need to install it, depending on your PHP version).

Comment: @FDL edit code and show me how please

Comment: add teh meta tag first on your header   after that check the code    out put    <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518021/508126

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to make your code UTF-8 aware is to use [`mbstring` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) instead of the plain dumb ones in the three cases where the latter appear:

```
function sentenceCase($str)
{
    $cap = true;
    $ret = '';
    for ($x = 0; $x < mb_strlen($str); $x++) {      // mb_strlen instead
        $letter = mb_substr($str, $x, 1);           // mb_substr instead
        if ($letter == "." || $letter == "!" || $letter == "?") {
            $cap = true;
        } elseif ($letter != " " && $cap == true) {
            $letter = mb_strtoupper($letter);       // mb_strtoupper instead
            $cap = false;
        }
        $ret .= $letter;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

You can then configure `mbstring` to work with UTF-8 strings and you are ready to go:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo sentenceCase ("üias skdfnsknka");
```

**Bonus solution**

Specifically for UTF-8 you can also use a regular expression, which will result in less code:

```
$str = "üias skdfnsknka";
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/((?:^|[!.?])\s*)(\p{Ll})/u',
    function($match) { return $match[1].mb_strtoupper($match[2], 'UTF-8'); },
    $str);
```

Comment: it capitalized every word, not starting one. I need sentence case not, every word

Comment: @heron: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. I updated the answer.

Comment: doesn't work for me. result is same as argument passed into function

Comment: @heron: The script contains a string literal. Is it saved as UTF-8? If it is, there is no reason why this would not work.