# Uppercase first letter and rest lower

Tags: php, ucfirst

Ive been looking around for a way in PHP to have a string converted, so that the first letter becomes uppercase and the rest lower case.

At the moment I am doing what I believe is the standard way:

```
ucfirst(strtolower($string));
```

But I have found that some programming languages (ie. tcl) can do it with one cammand:

```
totitle
```

Is there a way to do this in PHP?
It's not a problem as such, I'm just a curios dude :D

Thanks

Comment: No. If the string is all caps no matter which function you use you will need to convertt it to lowercase first before call ucwords() or ucfirst().

Comment: Yes: `function totitle($string) { return ucfirst(strtolower($string));} echo totitle('my MIXED case STRING');` The whole point of a programming language is that you can write code to do things like this for you.... if all programming language did exactly the same things in exactly the same way, the would be only one, highlander

Answer (score 4):

```
function totitle($string){
  return ucfirst(strtolower($string));
}
```

And voila :)

Comment: Dude read user3139907 question... he used totitle... I just copy passed what the author used.

Answer (score 0):

"Title" casing capitalizes each *word* in a string (i.e. every letter following white space).  Your approach would result in "Gone with the wind," whereas title casing would yield "Gone With The Wind".

I wouldn't worry about it:  what you're doing is simple and intuitive, and if it gets you what you want, there's not any intrinsic functions that do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such function yourself.

Do not forget that you should use `mb_*` functions for data that was input by user. English is not the only language people use. Look at this question: [ucfirst() function for multibyte character encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2517947/1833960)

Answer (score 0):

You should go like this

```
<?php
$string= 'HELLO WORLD';
$string = strtolower($string);
$string = ucfirst($string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a single, native function that performs title-casing and is multibyte-safe. This is a very tidy solution because you don't need to prepare the string to be all lowercase before making the leading letter of all words uppercase.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HZbQn))

```
$string = "OH HeLlo world, it'S \"NiCE\" 'to' sEe you!";
echo mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
```

Output:

```
Oh Hello World, It's "Nice" 'To' See You!
```

The above demonstrates that the coment at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php#119629 is incorrect about the behavior relating to double-quote wtapped words.

---

Also, in Laravel, there is a helper method that can be mentioned: `title()`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$converted = Str::of('a nice title uses the correct case')->title();

// A Nice Title Uses The Correct Case
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-title

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple words in your string, `ucwords()` can convert the first letter of each word to uppercase.

```
$string = 'hello world HELLO, wORlD HOW are You';
echo upperLowerCase($string);

function upperLowerCase($string) {
  return ucwords(strtolower($string));
}
```

Comment: mickmackusa; My bad. I was looking for a function like this myself, so I accidentally missed the actual original question.

Comment: Your advice is already found at this more appropriate page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32564539/2943403