# Converting php string to Title Case

Tags: php, string, title-case

I want to convert an input string to Title Case.

So, if I have an input string

```
Name: MR. M.A.D KARIM
```

I want to produce the following output string

```
Name: M.A.D Karim
```

And if I have an input string

```
Address: 12/A, ROOM NO-B 13
```

I want to produce

```
Address: 12/A, Room No-B 13
```

I want my output string to have a capital letter after any whitespace character, as well as after any of the following characters: `.`, `-`, `/`.

My current solution is

```
ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

But it leaves characters after `.`,  `-` and `/` lowercased, while I want them to be uppercased.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68758674/2943403) that is suitable for one of the two input strings in this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php


    $str = "Name: MR. M.A.D KARIM";
    $result = "";

    $arr = array();
    $pattern = '/([;:,-.\/ X])/';
    $array = preg_split($pattern, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach($array as $k => $v)
        $result .= ucwords(strtolower($v));

    //$result = str_replace("Mr.", "", $result); ->If you don't want Mr. in a String
    echo $result;



?>
```

Input:

```
Name: MR. M.A.D KARIM
Address: 12/A, ROOM NO-B 13
```

Output:

```
Name: M.A.D Karim
Address: 12/A, Room No-B 13
```

Comment: Are there any utility libraries for PHP that do this?

Comment: Why you use X in pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Stringy](https://github.com/voku/Stringy)

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "voku/stringy": "~5.0"
}
```

**PHP**

```
Stringy::create('string')->toTitleCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

While not 100% correct for both of your input strings, `mb_convert_case()` is an excellent tool for this type of task because it is a single, native function.

To implement you custom handling for specific sequences in the input string, `preg_replace_callback()` is appropriate. I'll use multibyte safe pattern techniques so that the entire solution remains multibyte/unicode safe.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pvCjU))

```
function titleCaseSpecial($string)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '~[/.-]\p{Ll}~u',
        function ($m) {
            return mb_strtoupper($m[0], 'UTF-8');
        },
        mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8')
    );
}

$strings = [
    'Name: MR. M.A.D KARIM',
    'Address: 12/A, ROOM NO-B 13'
];

var_export(
    array_map('titleCaseSpecial', $strings)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Name: Mr. M.A.D Karim',
  1 => 'Address: 12/A, Room No-B 13',
)
```

P.s. I am assuming the missing `Mr.` in the question is just a posting error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 8 Years old but, [`ucwords`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) already provides such functionality since PHP 5.4.32
It's as simple as:

```php
<?php
echo ucwords(strtolower("Address: 12/A, ROOM NO-B 13"), ".-/ ");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: OP said that `ucwords()` wasn't quite the correct solution: "But it leaves characters after `.`, `-` and `/` lowercased, while I want them to be uppercased."

Comment: @PatJ That is because the command is missing the second argument, which I've provided in my answer. And PHP 5.4.32 came out 2 months before this question was asked I consider it to be a correct solution even back then when the question was asked

Comment: Whoops, my mistake.