# why the php ucfirst error, why?

Tags: php, ucfirst

@see: (on mac os):

```
developer:php $ php -v
```

PHP 5.5.24 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2015 11:18:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

```
developer:php $ php -r "echo ucfirst('the test') . PHP_EOL;"
```

The test

```
developer:php $ php -r "echo ucfirst('中文') . PHP_EOL;"
```

ĸ?文    <<<<

Please help me , 3Q!

PS: php5.6 is same!

Comment: I don't think that php can handle chinese letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a charset encoding thing where you need a multi-byte function. This other question says there is no mb_ucfirst but has a solution listed:

[ucfirst() function for multibyte character encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517947/ucfirst-function-for-multibyte-character-encodings)

Comment: why my friends are OK in!  and i test some php version, port install and source installed, then are same problem.