# Scandinavian letters (å ä ö) not displaying correctly

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I know there are plenty of related topics about this issue, but I haven't been able to fix the problem with any of them.

I have a MySQL table with words and some of them can contain scandinavian letters, such as å, ä and ö. When I output them simply with `echo` or `print_r()`, the output is always �. I have tried using `utf8_encode()`, which shows a different invalid result. Using `mb_detect_encoding()`, I have noticed the encoding of the words containing these letters is UTF-8 already.

Example words:

```
A = the word (and expected output)
B = echo word
C = echo utf8_encode(word)
D = mb_detect_encoding(word)
E = mb_detect_encoding(utf8_encode(word))

+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| word  | word  | word  | ASCII | ASCII |
|  työ  |  ty�  | tyã¶  | UTF-8 | UTF-8 |
|  ylä  |  yl�  | ylã¤  | UTF-8 | UTF-8 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The collation of all of my MySQL tables is set to `utf8 - utf8_swedish_ci` and when initializing PDO I have

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=yyyy;charset=utf8", "zzzz", "****");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Also, the encoding of all of my files is set to *UTF-8 without BOM* and before outputting I have `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Using `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` in the beginning of PHP file does nothing.

**So, the question is - how can I actually output the words correctly?** I'd also like to know why is `utf8_encode()` changing the output from wrong (UTF-8) to different wrong (still UTF-8) so I'd actually learn something about this mess called encoding.

Comment: Is your file AS UTF-8 and not as ANSI?

Comment: Yes, all of my files are set as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Did you go through this yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I did now. Tried changing collation and charset at db init to utf8mb4 but it didn't change anything. Also checked [this](http://www.sebastianviereck.de/en/php-mysql-special-characters-umlauts-utf8-iso/) - there must be a better way than using `str_replace()`.

Comment: low tech solution: convert them with `htmlentities` before you store them in the db http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=latin

Comment: What does `echo rawurlencode($word)` say?

Comment: Also your data looks like `strtolower` has been applied to utf8 strings. Did you do that?

Comment: @georg You are right, I did use `strtolower`, straight after pulling the data from DB. Now after investigating [I found out it was a terrible idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516448/problems-with-strtolower-function). Damn PHP5 and multi-byte characters! Thank you for pointing me at the correct answer!

Comment: when handling multibyte encoding (like UTF-8) the way to go is using mb_* variants like 'mb_strtolower'. For a reference on using unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: Probably you should answer your question. It's still on "unanswered" list :)

Comment: @Paul Tomkiel Thanks for reminding! I thought it would have been silly to answer my own question (especially when someone else provided the answer!) but as it has been so long, it's best to get it on the answered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by using `strtolower` on the strings.

Apparently [PHP5 is not UTF-8 compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516448/problems-with-strtolower-function) and regular string manipulation does not work on multi-byte characters.

The solution was using `mb_strtolower` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)) instead with UTF-8 encoding.

More info: [Function Overloading Feature](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) (provided by [Blablaenzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3200414/blablaenzo))

Thanks [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753104/scandinavian-letters-%C3%A5-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-not-displaying-correctly?noredirect=1#comment40271074_25753104)!